# Como hacer una consulta mysql y abrir el enlace? c# y asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, vb, onclick

Tengo una tabla en la base de datos donde tengo guardados distintos enlaces. Sería posible mediante un onclick leer la consulta y abrir el enlace que quiera? No se si me explico.

Un saludo y muchas gracias de antemano!!

Edito. Tengo lo siguiente, pero no funciona:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Datos.aspx.cs/GetUrl",
        data: '{name: "' + $("#<%=prueba1.ClientID%>")[0].value + '" }',
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
dataType: "json",
success: OnSuccess,
failure: function (response) {
    alert(response.d);
}
});


public string GetUrl(string id)
{

    string cadConexion = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["gestionTienda"].ConnectionString;
    MySqlConnection conexion = new MySqlConnection(cadConexion);
    MySqlCommand operacion = new MySqlCommand("select destino_enlace from tutoriales where id='14'", conexion);
    MySqlDataReader lector;
    conexion.Open();
    //  operacion.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ori", editado.Nick);
    lector = operacion.ExecuteReader();

    string url = Convert.ToString(operacion.ExecuteScalar());

        return url;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Podrias hacer una llaamada `ajax` a una `webmethod` para obtener la url y luego aplicar el

```
window.localtion.href= 'url';
```

con esto navegarias a esa url que recuperas

El tema de usar `$.ajax` de `jquery` es que puedes programar en codigo cliente y aplicarlo en el `onclick` sin necesidad de un `post` al servidor.

[Calling ASP.Net WebMethod using jQuery AJAX](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Calling-ASPNet-WebMethod-using-jQuery-AJAX.aspx)

En el ejemplo veras como utiliza

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "WebPage1.aspx/GetCurrentTime",
    data: '{name: "' + $("#<%=txtUserName.ClientID%>")[0].value + '" }',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: OnSuccess,
    failure: function(response) {
        alert(response.d);
    }
});
```

Para invocar al servidor en un

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static string GetCurrentTime(string name)
{
    //aqui recuperas la url de la db y la retornas como respuesta
    return "url";
}
```

La consulta `MySql` seria algo como lo siguiente

```
public string GetUrl(string id)
{
    string constring = "<connection string>";
    using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(constring)) {   
        conn.Open();   

        string query = "SELECT url FROM Tabla WHERE id = @id";   
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, conn);   

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?id", id);     

        string url = Convert.ToString(cmd.ExecuteScalar());   

        return url;
    } 
}
```

al usar el `ExecuteScalar()` solo obtienes un valor simple, por eso se define un unico campo en el select y debes pasarle algun parametro del filtro para localizar el registro

Comment: porque negativo, que me falto? que ven incorrecto en la respuesta? esa costumbre de poner negativo sin explicarse, si me dicen que me falta puedo ampliar la respuesta, sino me dicen nada como puedo mejorar no ayuda en nada

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, pero de cara a una consulta MYSQL como podría ampliar esa funcionalidad?

Comment: edite la respuesta agregando como seria al consulta mysql, por supuesto recuerda instalar el conector de mysql para tener las dll de ado.net que se requieren

Comment: He editado mi post de arriba con lo que tengo hecho. Lo que hace ahora mismo es recargar la misma pagina. No lee ningun enlace. El botón es el siguiente: 
   <asp:Button runat="server" ID="prueba1" style="height:30px" alt="Subir escudo 
    del club" />

Comment: Eso que has puesto como `GetUrl()` no es un webmethod, si revisas debes ponerlo como static y ademas con el atributo `[WebMethod]`. Ademas la url no puede tener `.aspx.cs` eso es el archivo de codigo no la pagina, solo debes poner `.aspx` nada mas

Comment: He solucionado lo que has comentado, pero creo que no lee bien la función, porque no hace nada. En el evento onclick no lee la URL.

Comment: Si pones un breakpoint en el webmethod se detiene la ejecucion ? puedes ver en el developer tools del browser, al cual accedes con F12 si hay un error en la solapa console